# Why would auto-generated WP8 initialization code fail?

Tags: c#, initialization, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator

The "RootFrame = " line in this code, all of which is auto-generated:

```
private void InitializePhoneApplication()
{
    if (phoneApplicationInitialized)
        return;

    // Create the frame but don't set it as RootVisual yet; this allows the splash
    // screen to remain active until the application is ready to render.
    RootFrame = new PhoneApplicationFrame();
    RootFrame.Navigated += CompleteInitializePhoneApplication;

    // Handle navigation failures
    RootFrame.NavigationFailed += RootFrame_NavigationFailed;

    // Handle reset requests for clearing the backstack
    RootFrame.Navigated += CheckForResetNavigation;

    // Ensure we don't initialize again
    phoneApplicationInitialized = true;
}
```

...fails with:

> *System.TypeInitializationException was unhandled by user code   HResult=-2146233036   Message=The type initializer for
>   'TaSLS_PhoneApp.App' threw an exception.   Source=TaSLS_PhoneApp
>   TypeName=TaSLS_PhoneApp.App   StackTrace:
>          at TaSLS_PhoneApp.App.set_RootFrame(PhoneApplicationFrame value)
>          at TaSLS_PhoneApp.App.InitializePhoneApplication()
>          at TaSLS_PhoneApp.App..ctor()   InnerException: System.NotImplementedException
>          HResult=-2147467263
>          Message=The method or operation is not implemented.
>          Source=Windows
>          StackTrace:
>               at Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.get_RoamingSettings()
>               at TaSLS_PhoneApp.App..cctor()
>          InnerException:*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root cause isn't the generated code, but your code that it is calling...

> TaSLS_PhoneApp.App.InitializePhoneApplication() at TaSLS_PhoneApp.App..ctor() 
>   InnerException: System.NotImplementedException HResult=-2147467263 Message=The method or 
>   operation is not implemented. Source=Windows StackTrace: at 
>   Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.get_RoamingSettings() at TaSLS_PhoneApp.App..cctor() 
>   InnerException:*

It looks like in your app's `InitializePhoneApplication` is calling a WinRT function which isn't implemented on Windows phone 8. See MSDN documentation at:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.roamingsettings.